# sopt value to ignore case sensitivity

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

In my struts2jquery grid I've given

```
<sj:gridColumn name="processName" index="processName" title="Process Name" search="true" searchoptions="{sopt: ['bw','cn']}"/>
```

For sopt we've values like

`{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']}`

Now I want to get the data in grid by ignoring the letter case. But it is filtering data if we search in the same way we stored. i.e; (say) If I stored data starting with 'D' it won't filter data starting with 'd'. How can I solve this. Is there any option for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

this link should help you [struts2 jquery plugin wiki grid](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SearchGrid).

you should define your own search action class to do the search. btw, it should be **`<sjg:gridColumn/>`** o_O

Comment: Oh sorry, it's <sjg:gridColumn/>, when I entered here some mistake came. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution with the JavaScript:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<div id="prije">Prije</div>


<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable" />

<sjg:grid id="gridtableID" 

    caption="Primjer JSON TABELE" 
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}" 
    gridModel="gridModel" 
    viewrecords="true"
    pager="true"
    pagerPosition="centar"
    navigator="true"
    navigatorSearch="true"
    filter="true"
    filterOptions="{stringResult:true}"
    loadonce="true"

     >

    <sjg:gridColumn name="id"
        index="id" title="ID" 
        formatter="integer"
        search="false"
        searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"
        editable="false" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"
        search="true"
        searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country"
        search="true"
        searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" search="true"
        searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit"
        title="Credit Limit" formatter="currency" search="true"
        searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"/>

</sjg:grid>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gridtableID").jqGrid('setGridParam', { ignoreCase: true});
    });
</script>
```